# Making an album and posting and image into it

Tags: facebook

Hey guys am new to facebook js sdk.I have decided to run the code which makes an album and post an image into it.So i have tried my code like

```
function testAPI() {


{
        message: "I am the album desc - test 2",
        url: "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3332/3451193407_b7f047f4b4_o.jpg",
        name: "Some Name" };



FB.api('/me/albums', 'post', album_details,  function(response){  });

  }
```

The code just works fine .A new album is made with the code but the image is not displayed inside it..The album is empty ..How can i add an image into that album ??

Thanx for your help..:)

Comment: Duplicate of [Making album and add images at same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315754/making-album-and-add-images-at-same-time)

Comment: @CBroe  i didnt get an answer for that question ..i have shown you the code but this isnt working ..i have tried concatenating `'/me/'+response.id+'/photos'` but this isnt working

Comment: @CBroe please help me by providing a corect answer

Comment: @CBroe can you help me ..can you point me what am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just read the documentation, then you'd see what's wrong:

First you have to create a new album, as described in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/albums#publish

Call:

```
POST /v2.2/me/albums
```

Take the `album_id` from the response, and use this to post the photo:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album/photos#publish

The call must be

```
POST /me/{album_id}/photos
```

And you'll need the `publish_actions` permission for that.

Comment: how can i get the id of the album before its made..am trying to generate an album with an image as together

Comment: You need to create the album first. It's all in the docs! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/albums#publish

Comment: see i have passed the url option into the code as the doc says...and i have the  publish_actions permission too..but am still confused with the album id ..how can i add an id ?..i want to add an image at the same time of album creation

Comment: Just because you whish to do this doesn't mean that it's possible. You receive the `album_id` in the response to the creation request. RTFM!

Comment: can you please post the code by making some edit in ur answer ..:/

Comment: No, I won't code your program for you. It's all in the docs. First, create the album, take the `album_id` from the response and second, post the photo to the new album.

Comment: i have used response.album_id at the place of {album_id} in api..but still it didnt works

Comment: see my code ..its not working ..it would be realy helpful if you post the working code or give me the right path http://pastebin.com/FeKXZGJd

Comment: ..can you help me if you know the way on how to do this ??..cuz i have tried many codes but it doesnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315754/making-album-and-add-images-at-same-time